# Input string is not in correct format

Tags: c#, .net

```
string CommandText = "insert into dbo.printing_list(batch_code,bill_no,date,sr_no,gross_wt,core_wt,nett_wt,c_id,category) values('" + 
                      comboBox2.Text.ToString() + 
                      "','" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "','" + 
                      dateTimePicker1.Value + "','" +
                      dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value + "','" +
                      Convert.ToDecimal(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value) + 
                      "','" + Convert.ToDecimal(label2.Text.ToString()) + "','" + 
                      dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value + "','" + g + "','" +
                      comboBox1.Text.ToString() + "')";
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please try the [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=input+string+is+not+in+correct+format), you're not the first to run into this error. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster: 2742 hits :-) **DEFINITELY** not the first .....

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. First of all, you should read [FAQ] and [ask] couple of times. Second of all, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for _SQL Injection_ attacks.

Comment: I hope someone will turn it into Parameter version for the OP :)

Comment: I think I just had an aneurysm trying to read this...

Answer (score 4):

You must use  parametrized queries instead of string concatination.

modify your c# code with this :

```
string connString = "Your connection string here";
using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
  cn.Open();
  string query = "insert into dbo.printing_list(batch_code,bill_no,date,sr_no,gross_wt,core_wt,nett_wt,c_id,category) values(@batch_code,@bill_no,@date ,@sr_no,@gross_wt,@core_wt,@nett_wt,@c_id,@category)";

  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query , cn);
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@batch_code , cast_value_retrieved_from_your_control));
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@bill_no , cast_value_retrieved_from_your_control));
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@date , cast_value_retrieved_from_your_control));
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@sr_no , cast_value_retrieved_from_your_control));
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@gross_wt , cast_value_retrieved_from_your_control));
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@core_wt , cast_value_retrieved_from_your_control));
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@nett_wt , cast_value_retrieved_from_your_control));
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@c_id , cast_value_retrieved_from_your_control));
  cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(@category , cast_value_retrieved_from_your_control));
  int retval = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  if(retval > 0)
  {
      //A Label you can keep your page for showing message - named as "Label1"
       Label1.Text = "Inserted Successfully";
  }
}
```

Comment: just a suggestion to the readers:Its is preferred to put the datatypes also while passing it ex:SqlDBType.int for type integer